# $facebook->get_loggedin_user(); is Undefined?

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

This question was asked before, but it wasn't answered properly. Can someone please explain how to fix this problem? Right now I am just including facebook.php file from the PHP SDK. And the following code is giving me the error:

```
$facebook->get_loggedin_user();

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::get_loggedin_user()
```

Any idea what to do?

---

So I was just informed that the old API is not going to work anymore. If anyone has a link to a good tutorial to use the new (Graph?) API, please share. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using documentation from the old api with the new SDK, which does not have that method and follows a completely different flow.

Check usage here: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

Either way if you want serious help you should provide more info (SDK version, contextual code).

Comment: That is the SDK I used, but i am using the old API. Do you have a link to a good tutorial on the new API?

Comment: Right here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, combined with the link in my answer that should give you everything you need to get started.